# Laravel Confide using wrong table on save

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Confide and Entrust with Laravel 4.

When i try and create a new user, it keeps coming up with a strange error. The users are stored in Admin, and i can edit/select users, but not create them. For some reason, it's somewhere referencing the wrong table. No errors come back or anything, just a SQL error. I cannot seem to find where it comes up though.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `username` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'blah', ))
```

That's the SQL error and below is the php code.

```
$user = new Admin();
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Input::get('password');
$user->save();
```

Admin Modal: http://pastebin.com/3jEM4dFk

Even though my modal is set to pull everything from Admin, it tries and get's a count from users.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: can you post your Admin model?

Comment: I added a pastebin link in :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this was already reported on [Zizaco Confide github issues page](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/94)

What you need is custom validation rules, because by default rules Confide is checking the unique constraint on user table fields.

[as @edrands states in his comment:](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/94#issuecomment-19003256)

```
"I may have solved what was causing the first point. The validation rules are checking for a unique in the users table. I just need custom rules."
```

Comment: glad I could help. If you find my answer useful, please accept it as the proper solution to your problem and +1 it - so others can easily find it when they face the same errors as you did.